# Genesys BYOC Purecloud Outgoing Call issue

Tags: call, wireshark, sip, pbx, sip-server

We recently implemented Genesys BYOC PureCloud in our organization, and we have encountered an issue with outgoing calls not working. I would like to provide some background information on our setup and the problem we are facing.

We have a Yeastar S300 PBX in our organization, and we created a SIP trunk with the peer method to connect to Genesys Edge VM, which acts as a PBX. We have set up the routing so that calls coming to a specific number (call center) are routed to Genesys Edge VM. While incoming calls are working perfectly, outgoing calls are not working, and we are receiving a 603 decline error from the PBX.

To troubleshoot the issue, we have captured the packet using Wireshark, which confirmed that the call is being rejected by the PBX with the 603 decline error. We have checked the SIP trunk configuration and ensured that the authentication credentials and codecs are correctly configured. We have also checked our dial plan and verified that the number we are calling is correctly formatted and allowed.

Despite our efforts, we are still facing the issue with outgoing calls not working, can anyone help us with issue??

To troubleshoot the issue, we have captured the packet using Wireshark, which confirmed that the call is being rejected by the PBX with the 603 decline error. We have checked the SIP trunk configuration and ensured that the authentication credentials and codecs are correctly configured. We have also checked our dial plan and verified that the number we are calling is correctly formatted and allowed.